# How can I change the first day of week in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I'm using a plugin [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) to deal with NSDate. But I have a problem that`weekOfYear` of date `2015-08-08` (Saturday) is not equals to `weekOfYear` of date `2015-08-08` (Sunday), I think is the problem of `. firstDayOfWeek`, but I don't know how to change it. And here is the code:

```
let date1: NSDate = NSDate.date(fromString: "2015-08-08", format: DateFormat.Custom("yyyy-MM-dd"))!
let date2: NSDate = NSDate.date(fromString: "2015-08-09", format: DateFormat.Custom("yyyy-MM-dd"))!
if (date1.weekOfYear != date2.weekOfYear) {
    print("!!!")
}
```

Can anyone help? I really need this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar();
calendar.firstWeekday = 2;
let date1: NSDate = NSDate.date(fromString: "2015-08-08", format: DateFormat.Custom("yyyy-MM-dd"))!
let date2: NSDate = NSDate.date(fromString: "2015-08-09", format: DateFormat.Custom("yyyy-MM-dd"))!

var weekNum1 = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: date1).weekOfYear;
var weekNum2 = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: date2).weekOfYear;

if(weekNum1 != weekNum2){
    //do here
}
```

Comment: error: `'NSCalendarUnit.Type' does not have a member named 'CalendarUnitWeekOfYear'`

Comment: line `var weekNum1 = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: date1).weekOfYear;`

Comment: Yeah! I solved this by change `calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: date1).weekOfYear` into `Int(calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear, fromDate: date1).weekOfYear)`, I think is the problem about Swift 2.0's syntax change.